# Shell script current directory?

Tags: linux, directory, sh, working-directory

What is current directory of shell script? Is this current directory from which I called it? Or this directory where the script is located?

Comment: See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory) which is superficially about Python but also relevant here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The current(initial) directory of shell script is the directory from which you have called the script.

Answer (score 214):

As already mentioned, the location will be where the script was called from. If you wish to have the script reference it's installed location, it's quite simple. Below is a snippet that will print the PWD and the installed directory:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script executed from: ${PWD}"

BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)
echo "Script location: ${BASEDIR}"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It only gives the name of the containing dir, not the full path. For example, if I do that from a script in `/home/user/scripts/x.sh`, it returns `scripts`, not `/home/user/scripts`.

Comment: I think this is because your current working directory is `/home/user` and you called the script by `scripts/x.sh`. Hence, `$0` value inside the script is `scripts/x.sh`. In order to get the absolute path of the script, you can use `BASEDIR=$(cd $(dirname $0) && pwd)`

Answer (score 75):

Most answers get you the current path and are context sensitive. In order to run your script from any directory, use the below snippet.

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "$0" )" && pwd )"
```

By switching directories in a subshell, we can then call `pwd` and get the correct path of the script regardless of context.

You can then use `$DIR` as `"$DIR/path/to/file"`

Comment: Can you explain what's going on? When my script gets run more than 20 times simultaneously, I get the following error:
`....sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable`
The script gets run by OpenVPN. (under nogroup group and nobody account)

Comment: Another advantage of this example is that `readlink` and `realpath` doesn't work in Systemd unit files when they call a shell script. So this one is the most portable POSIX solution that I found so far.

Answer (score 8):

You could do this yourself by checking the output from `pwd` when running it.
This will print the directory **you are currently in**. Not the script.

If your script does not switch directories, it'll print the directory you **ran it from**.

Answer (score 7):

Adding to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889938/shell-script-current-directory#comment126417467_12761885) comment, I think most optimized and logic way is:

```
realpath `dirname $0`
```

or

```
realpath $(dirname $0)
```

Comment: How to [link to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/509881).

Answer (score 2):

To print the current working Directory i.e. pwd just type command like:

```
echo "the PWD is : ${PWD}"
```

Comment: Do you mean `${PWD}` ? Shell variable names are case sensitive and traditionally use upper case. `${pwd}` is not a predefined variable name unless you specifically set it to something.

Comment: `$(pwd)` may be better.

Answer (score 0):

you could also do it completely using posix shell script

```bash
#!/bin/sh

get_current_directory() {
    current_file="${PWD}/${0}"
    echo "${current_file%/*}"
}

CWD=$(get_current_directory)
echo "$CWD"
```