# What exactly is current working directory?

Tags: python, working-directory

My book states:

> Every program that runs on your computer has a current working directory, or cwd. Any filenames or paths that do not begin with the root folder are assumed to be under the current working directory

As I am on OSX, my root folder is /. When I type in `os.getcwd()` in my Python shell, I get `/Users/apple/Documents`. Why am I getting the Documents folder in my cwd? Is it saying that Python is using Documents folder? Isn't there any path heading to Python that begins with `/` (the root folder)?  Also, does every program have a different cwd?

Comment: *It depends.* On how the program was launched. If you go to your terminal, change to the Documents folder and type `$ python`, then Python will launch with a CWD of `/Users/apple/Documents`.

Comment: cwd stands for current working directory same as like pwd in linux. there is, `os.getcwd()` will give you the directory name in which you are executing it

Comment: Yes, if you ask Python what its cwd is and it says that it's the Documents directory, then the cwd is the Documents directory.

Comment: @JJJ , does that mean that I have started Python from the Documents folder? If not then what is the significance of Documents folder in cwd?

Comment: Shouldn't you know yourself where you started Python?

Comment: @JJJ , I have this little folder on the screen! :p
but yeah, Documents contains all the python files!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your python interpreter location is based off of how you launched it, as well as subsequent actions taken after launching it like use of the os module to navigate your file system. Merely starting the interpreter will place you in the directory of your python installation (not the same on different operating systems). On the other hand, if you start by editing or running a file within a specific directory, your location will be the folder of the file you were editing. If you need to run the interpreter in a certain directory and you are using idle for example, it is easiest to start by creating a python file there one way or another and when you edit it you can start a shell with Run > Python Shell which will already be in that directory. If you are using the command line interpreter, navigate to the folder where you want to run your interpreter before running the python/python3/py command. If you need to navigate manually, you can of course use the following which has already been mentioned:

```
import os
os.chdir('full_path_to_your_directory')
```

Answer (score 39):

Every process has a current directory. When a process starts, it simply inherits the current directory from its parent process; and it's not, for example, set to the directory which contains the program you are running.

For a more detailed explanation, read on.

When disks became large enough that you did not want all your files in the same place, operating system vendors came up with a way to structure files in *directories*. So instead of saving everything in the same directory (or "folder" as beginners are now taught to call it) you could create new collections and other new collections inside of those (except in some early implementations directories could not contain other directories!)

Fundamentally, a directory is just a peculiar type of file, whose contents is a collection of other files, which can also include other directories.

On a primitive operating system, that was where the story ended. If you wanted to print a file called `term_paper.txt` which was in the directory `spring_semester` which in turn was in the directory `2021` which was in the directory `studies` in the directory `mine`, you would have to say

```
print mine/studies/2021/spring_semester/term_paper.txt
```

(except the command was probably something more arcane than `print`, and the directory separator might have been something crazy like square brackets and colons, or something;

```
lpr [mine:studies:2021:spring_semester]term_paper.txt
```

but this is unimportant for this exposition) and if you wanted to copy the file, you would have to spell out the whole enchilada twice:

```
copy mine/studies/2021/spring_semester/term_paper.txt mine/studies/2021/spring_semester/term_paper.backup
```

Then came the concept of a current working directory. What if you could say "from now on, until I say otherwise, all the files I am talking about will be in this particular directory".  Thus was the `cd` command born (except on old systems like VMS it was called something clunkier, like `SET DEFAULT`).

```
cd mine/studies/2021/spring_semester
print term_paper.txt
copy term_paper.txt term_paper.backup
```

That's really all there is to it. When you `cd` (or, in Python, `os.chdir()`), you change your current working directory. It stays until you log out (or otherwise exit this process), or until you `cd` to a different working directory, or switch to a different process or window where you are running a separate command which has *its* own current working directory. Just like you can have your file browser (Explorer or Finder or Nautilus or whatever it's called) open with multiple windows in different directories, you can have multiple terminals open, and each one runs a shell which has its own independent current working directory.

So when you type `pwd` into a terminal (or `cwd` or whatever the command is called in your command language) the result will pretty much depend on what you happened to do in that window or process before, and probably depends on how you created that window or process. On many Unix-like systems, when you create a new terminal window with an associated shell process, it is originally opened in your home directory (`/home/you` on many Unix systems, `/Users/you` on a Mac, something more or less like `C:\Users\you` on recent Windows) though probably your terminal can be configured to open somewhere else (commonly `Desktop` or `Documents` inside your home directory on some ostensibly "modern" and "friendly" systems).

Many beginners have a vague and incomplete mental model of what happens when you run a program. Many will incessantly `cd` into whichever directory contains their script or program, and be genuinely scared and confused when you tell them that you don't have to.  If `frobozz` is in `/home/you/bin` then you don't have to

```
cd /home/you/bin
./frobozz
```

because you can simply run it directly with

```
/home/you/bin/frobozz
```

and similarly if `ls` is in `/bin` you most definitely don't

```
cd /bin
./ls
```

just to get a directory listing.

Furthermore, like the `ls` (or on Windows, `dir`) example should readily convince you, any program you run will look in *your* current directory for files. Not the directory the program or script was saved in. Because if that were the case, `ls` could only produce a listing of the directory it's in (`/bin`) -- there is nothing special about the directory listing program, or the copy program, or the word processor program; they all, by design, look in the current working directory (though again, some GUI programs will *start* with e.g. your `Documents` directory as their current working directory, by design, at least if you don't tell them otherwise).

Many beginners write scripts which demand that the input and output files are in a particular directory inside a particular user's home directory, but this is just poor design; a well-written program will simply look in the current working directory for its input files unless instructed otherwise, and write output to the current directory (or perhaps create a new directory in the current directory for its output if it consists of multiple files).

Python, then, is no different from any other programs.  If your current working directory is `/Users/you/Documents` when you run `python` then that directory is what `os.getcwd()` inside your Python script or interpreter will produce (unless you separately `os.chdir()` to a different directory during runtime; but again, this is probably unnecessary, and often a sign that a script was written by a beginner).  And if your Python script accepts a file name parameter, it probably should simply get the operating system to `open` whatever the user passed in, which means relative file names are relative to the invoking user's current working directory.

```
python /home/you/bin/script.py file.txt
```

should simply `open(sys.argv[1])` and fail with an error if `file.txt` does not exist in the current directory.  Let's say that again; it doesn't look in `/home/you/bin` for `file.txt` -- unless of course that is also the current working directory of you, the invoking user, in which case of course you could simply write

```
python script.py file.txt
```

On a related note, many beginners needlessly try something like

```
with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "input.txt")) as data:
    ...
```

which needlessly calls `os.getcwd()`. Why is it needless? If you have been following along, you know the answer already: the operating system will look for relative file names (like here, `input.txt`) in the current working directory anyway. So all you need is

```
with open("input.txt") as data:
    ...
```

One final remark. On Unix-like systems, all files are ultimately inside the root directory `/` which contains a number of other directories (and usually regular users are not allowed to write anything there, and system administrators with the privilege to do it typically don't want to).  Every relative file name can be turned into an absolute file name by tracing the path from the root directory to the current directory.  So if the file we want to access is in `/home/you/Documents/file.txt` it means that `home` is in the root directory, and contains `you`, which contains `Documents`, which contains `file.txt`. If your current working directory were `/home` you could refer to the same file by the relative path `you/Documents/file.txt`; and if your current directory was `/home/you`, the relative path to it would be `Documents/file.txt` (and if your current directory was `/home/you/Music` you could say `../Documents/file.txt` but let's not take this example any further now).

Windows has a slightly different arrangement, with a number of drives with single-letter identifiers, each with its own root directory; so the root of the C: drive is `C:\` and the root of the D: drive is `D:\` etc. (and the directory separator is a backslash instead of a slash, although you can use a slash instead pretty much everywhere, which is often a good idea for preserving your sanity).

Comment: The companion answer to [Difference between `./` and `~/`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435921/difference-between-and/55342466) explains similar concepts, with a focus on the difference between relative and absolute paths.

Comment: This answer more or less addresses the issue of what I did not understand even after reading dozens of answers to similar questions. However, I must ask: what is your objection to the use of the term "folder" in place of "directory"?

Comment: @Junglemath Thanks for the feedback (-: There is no strong objection _per se_ but it seems that "folder" was introduced for no good reason because somebody thought "directory" would induce anxiety in pants-wetters or something. The old one is a perfectly good term, and having two just creates confusion.

Comment: If you want to open a data file which is saved in the same directory as your Python script, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060221/how-to-reliably-open-a-file-in-the-same-directory-as-the-currently-running-scrip

Answer (score 7):

This has nothing to do with osx in particular, it's more of a concept shared by all unix-based systems, and I believe Windows as well. `os.getcwd()` is the equivalent of the bash `pwd` command - it simply returns the full path of the current location in which you are in. In other words:

```
alex@suse:~> cd /
alex@suse:/> python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul 01 2016, 15:34:22) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/'
```

It depends from where you started the python shell/script.

Comment: Why am I getting Documents folder in my cwd? Does that mean that I have started Python from the Documents folder?

Comment: Exit the shell and type `pwd` in the os shell. Where you start a script/shell and how you should structure it is your job and boils down to what it is you are trying to do.

Comment: When I typed `pwd` in the Terminal, I got `/Users/apple` . Now are you trying to say?

Comment: If possible you could please precisely explain the book statement itself!? It seems to go over my head

Answer (score 3):

Python is usually (except if you are working with virtual environments) accessible from any of your directory. You can check the variables in your path and Python should be available. So the directory you get when you ask Python is the one in which you started Python. Change directory in your shell before starting Python and you will see the output you get will change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

`os.getcwd()` has nothing to do with OSX in particular. It simply returns the directory/location of the source-file. If my source-file is on my desktop it would return `C:\Users\Dave\Desktop\` or let say the source-file is saved on an external storage device it could return something like `G:\Programs\`. It is the same for both unix-based and Windows systems.

Comment: Thanks Davey! 
But I am using the program itself and not a file! 
If I were using a file, then I do agree with you, it should give Documents Folder. 
What about the program itself? It is surely not in the Documents folder!

Comment: @M.Hamel In that case it depends on how python is installed on your machine. On my machine if I run the `os.getcwd() ` command from the Python console it returns `C:\Program Files\Python 35-32`.

Comment: `os.getcwd()` does not necessarily return the directory/location of the source file. It returns the _current working directory_ which may or may not be the same location.