# python logging - where has the log file gone

Tags: python, logging

I am trying to add logging to my script,and followed [python logging tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial)

> example code
>
> ```
> import logging
>
> logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
> logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
> logging.info('So should this')
> logging.warning('And this, too')
> ```

But I cannot find the `example.log` file at the directory where the script is in.And as I call `os.getcwd()`,it returns `C:\\users\\eda`.No log is there either.

Comment: Why don't you use an absolute path?

Comment: If you are using it in a script, it should be in the same folder as the script

Comment: look at this example https://docs.python.org/2.3/lib/node304.html

Comment: One gotcha is that you can't call `basicConfig` a second time; if you called it before (say in the REPL while playing around) then new calls will basically have no effect.

Comment: @tripleee In fact, I just found out that if you call any logging call prior to calling basicConfig, it will be called for you, with no arguments!  And subsequent calls won't reconfigure! I've spent a few hours trying to figure out why I wasn't creating log files!!

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with your script. However, be clear that the log file will be saved in the same directory as that from which the script was invoked, since you didn't specify an absolute path.

The screenshot below may help clarify this further:

[image: Tremendously clarifying screen shot]

Comment: For me it is not saved in the same directory :( Look at the screen shot in the below answer.

Comment: Probably you also need to understand the concept of current working directory. See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)