# PyGTK Builder add_from_file() different path approach with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, gtk3, execution

Well, in my `app/view.py` there's the a function call to `GTK.Builder().add_from_file("AppView.glade")`, however I observed it has been interpreted differently depending of how I execute the code.

```
project
|-- app
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- model.py
|   |-- view.py
|   |-- ...
|
|-- test
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- model.py
|   |-- ...
|
|-- ui
    |-- AppView.glade
```

When I regularly execute (`python3 -m app`) or test (`python3 -m unittest test`) the project, the `add_from_file` function expect the relative path from project root, that is `ui/AppView.glade`.

However, when I run or debug from PyCharm project's test or execution it expect a relative path from the file is calling the function, for this case `../ui/AppView.

Could I change this PyCharm behavior?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory

Comment: go to `edit configurations` and change working directory there