# VS Code code command not working anymore on terminal on Pop OS

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, zsh

I know this is a common asked question. I've searched and the answers didn't help, as many of them are for OSx and WSL. I'm on Pop!_OS.

I'm a VS Code user and I'm used to type `code .` to open my current folder on VS Code. But as of today, this doesn't happen anymore.

[image: code . = command not found]

The many answers I found tell me to `ctrl+shift+p` on VS Code and type `install` to find a command that installs the shell. It's not available for me.

[image: vscode printscreen showing aforementioned explanation]

Specs:

- Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS x86_64
- VS Code 1.53.2
- zsh 5.8 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu) + Oh My Zsh

Comment: Martin's answer worked. I didn't want to add more things to my .zshrc though. Reinstalling and installing VS Code through the Pop Shop fixed the issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In my case, I created a symbolic link.

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/
$ sudo ln -s /usr/share/code/bin/code code
```

from there on I could use `code` from wherever in the terminal (I also use Pop OS).

Comment: Thank you! That also worked for me running Pop Os 20.04 LTS

Comment: The `cd` is superfluous as such; `ln -s /usr/share/code/bin/code /usr/local/bin` from anywhere in the file system. Perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue and I am guessing the installation directory of VScode was moved during the VScode update (I think that's when it stopped working for me). Anyway, this is what I added to my .zshrc file to make it work:

`export PATH="/usr/share/code/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 3):

I added
**export PATH="/usr/share/code/bin:$PATH"**
to .bashrc and restarted Terminal and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue so I uninstall vscode and install it using snap:

```
sudo snap install code --classic
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are installing from Pop!_Shop confirm if it's deb instead of flatpak.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34197498)