# How to run a cmd command in Python using subprocess.run()

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to run the following command in Python after I have cd in `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\javaw.exe`

"@C:\Users\danie\IdeaProjects\EV_example\EV_example\matsim-libs\contribs\ev.temp-ChargerLocation-args-1617369801473.txt"
When being in cmd I can simply move to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\javaw.exe` and then execute the `"@C:\Users\danie\IdeaProjects\EV_example\EV_example\matsim-libs\contribs\ev\.temp-ChargerLocation-args-1617369801473.txt"`. It should include the quotation marks in order to correctly run.

however, when I am using the `subprocess.run(["cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\javaw.exe", ""@C:\Users\danie\IdeaProjects\EV_example\EV_example\matsim-libs\contribs\ev\.temp-ChargerLocation-args-1617369801473.txt""])` the command seems to gets confused with the double quotation marks, (see photo attached).

[image]

Is there any way to be able to run that just like being in my cmd but to be called from Python?

Comment: You can escape a character in Python code using \

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages;](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) tiny low-contrast images add insult to injury, and should already by themselves convince you why ttis is a bad idea.

Comment: To be honest, I would use `os.system` to run commands in a shell.

Comment: @coderman1234, I managed running it with os.system like this: `os.system(r'"java.exe @C:\Users\danie\IdeaProjects\EV_example\EV_example\matsim-libs\contribs\ev\.temp-ChargerLocation-args-1617369801473.txt"')`
However, although this is working perfect I am trying to do exactly the same think for another java class : `os.system(r'"java.exe @C:\Users\danie\IdeaProjects\EV_example\EV_example\matsim-libs\contribs\ev\.temp-MyRunEvExample-args-1617459572859.txt"')` but for this one I get the error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. 
The location and everything same.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no reason *per se* to `cd` to a specific directory to run a command whose binary is in that directory (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66860904/874188) but if you really need it, use the `cwd` keyword argument to `subprocess.run()`.

```py
subprocess.run([r"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\javaw.exe",
        r"@C:\Users\danie\IdeaProjects\EV_example\EV_example\matsim-libs\contribs\ev\.temp-ChargerLocation-args-1617369801473.txt"],
    # probably completely unnecessary
    cwd=r"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin",
    # probably also a good idea
    check=True)
```

In the absence of `shell=True`, no explicit quoting should be necessary or useful in the command string (though notice the raw string in order to correctly pass through the literal backslashes).

Comment: how can I run the following command in Python `/zhome/9e/b/129343/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.matsim.contrib.ev.example.MyRunEvExample"` ?
There is something wrong with the quotation marks.

Comment: Drop the quotes entirely; the shell would parse the command into exactly this, too. `subprocess.run(["/zhome/9e/b/129343/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn", "exec:java", "-Dexec.mainClass=org.matsim.contrib.ev.example.MyRunEvExample"])` and probably add `check=True` before the closing parenthesis.

Comment: You can use `printf '%s\n' /zhome/9e/b/129343/Maven/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="org.matsim.contrib.ev.example.MyRunEvExample"` to see this in action. Try the format string `'"%q"\n'` if you really want to see trailing spaces etc.

Answer (score 0):

To escape this you can use two different approaches. The first is just to escape all inner quotes like

```
subprocess.run([r"cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\javaw.exe",
    r"\"@C:\Users\danie\IdeaProjects\EV_example\EV_example\matsim-libs\contribs\ev\.temp-ChargerLocation-args-1617369801473.txt\""])
```

The second - use for string single quotes, if you need double quotes in it. Python doesn't make any difference between single and double quotes to indicate strings.

```
subprocess.run([r'cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin\javaw.exe',
    r'"@C:\Users\danie\IdeaProjects\EV_example\EV_example\matsim-libs\contribs\ev\.temp-ChargerLocation-args-1617369801473.txt"'])
```