# os.getcwd() returns directory one level up

Tags: python

I have a program which makes use of the current working directory.

The path of the file that im running is: /home/pi/Test/file.py

When running os.getcwd() the path returned is /home/pi/

the path i want is /home/pi/Test

what am i missing?

```
    osDir = os.getcwd()

month = osDir + "/" + month

print (osDir)
print (month)


if not os.path.exists(month):
        os.makedirs(month)
```

Using Python3 .

The command to run the file is pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python3 TEST/file.py

Comment: The current working directory is *not* the directory the source code file is in. A mismatch is normal.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory

Answer (score 2):

`os.getcwd()` does ***not*** return the path to the script; it returns the path to the folder where the script was started from, in your case `/home/pi`. If you want to get the absolute path to the python script, use `os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__))` instead.

And instead of `osDir + "/" + month` you should use `os.path.join(osDir, month)`.

Answer (score 0):

Relative path of the **file** `print(os.path.realpath(__file__))`

for **pathname** use `print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))`