# How do I run python script on specific folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, command-line-interface

I'm trying to run my python script against specific folder when I specify the folder name in the terminal e.g

```py
python script.py -'folder'

python script.py 'folder2'
```

'folder' being the I folder I would like to run the script in. Is there a command line switch that I must use?

Answer (score 1):

The `cd` command in the shell switches your current directory.

Perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

If you would like your Python script to accept a directory argument, you'll have to implement the command-line processing yourself. In its simplest form, it might look something like

```py
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    mydir = '.'
else:
    mydir = sys.argv[1]

do_things_with(mydir)
```

Usually, you would probably wrap this in `if __name__ == '__main__':` etc and maybe accept more than one directory and loop over the arguments?

```py
import sys
from os import scandir

def how_many_files(dirs):
    """
    Show the number of files in each directory in dirs
    """
    for adir in dirs:
        try:
            files = list(scandir(adir))
        except (PermissionError, FileNotFoundError) as exc:
            print('%s: %s' % (adir, exc), file=sys.stderr)
            continue
        print('%s: %i directory entries' % (adir, len(files)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    how_many_files(sys.argv[1:] or ['.'])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what I want to do is run my script against the sub-directory I specify..So if I want to the script to run inside folder2 I would just put $python script.py folder2

Comment: The second half of this answer explains exactly how to do this. If `script.py` should accept a command-line argument, it will need to pick it up from `sys.argv`. Of course, there are third-party libraries which help with this if you don't want to do it yourself, but without additional requirements, it's hard to recommend anything in particular.