# Python Virtualenv not creating the new environment in the directory I am

Tags: python, virtualenv

First of all, to put in context:

- I have installed Python 3.9 which comes from Visual Studio 2019
- I have installed Python 3.8 from Microsoft Store which installs it in the path:

  C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

Now I want to create a virtual environment for Python 3.8 so I can switch to it whenever I need. So I follow below steps (below commands are all executed from path C:\Users\username\AppData\Local):

1. Installing virtualenv:

   py -3.8 -m pip install virtualenv

[image]

2. Creating new virtual environment for Python 3.8:

   py -3.8 -m virtualenv _venv38.win32

[image]

And what's the surprise? Folder _venv38.win32 is not created within the directory I am which is C:\Users\username\AppData\Local

Instead _venv38.win32 is created in:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\Local\_venv38.win32
```

So why? I want it to be created in:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\_venv38.win32
```

which is the path from where I have executed the command (step 2)

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the third-party `virtualenv` over the standard `venv`?

Comment: @tripleee The only reason is that i googled and see that virtualenv was being used a lot so I decided to use it. Anyway the question here is: Why new virtual environment folder for Python 3.8 is not created in the same directory where I am executing the command? As I have understood from different sites, it creates the virtual environment folder in the same directory where I am but in my case it is not happening. I would like to know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
py -3.8 -m venv _venv38.win32
```

this will create `venv` at `cwd`.

`virtualenv` has a custom `"remote"` location for virtual environments somewhere outside your project

Comment: [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Comment: When I execute your command below error is thrown: Error: Command '['C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\_venv38.win32\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 106.

Comment: in your case it will be: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local`

Comment: I am not joking, honestly I didn't know what cwd means!

Comment: why you installed python from microsoft store? really, cmon man... go and install it manually from python.org

Comment: so. try again. install python3.8 from python.org. run `py -3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip`, then run `py -3.8 -m venv _venv38.win32`. and put your python.exe anywhere you want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241034/discussion-between-alexzander-and-ralph).

Comment: Finally it works. Thx.

Comment: Installing Python from Microsoft Store was causing problems. I downloaded Python 3.8 from python.org and install it. Now virtual environment is created in the same directory where I am and I execute the command.