# Running bash command in python

Tags: python, bash, operating-system, subprocess, command

I'm trying to run a long bash command with several pipes inside. I did some research and found the use of os.chdir() to change to a working directory, and subprocess to execute bash commands.

First I need to change into a directory that contains the file sample.txt

`os.chdir(path)`

This path will contain the file sample.txt

Then I ran the bash command using subprocess (for the `sed` command, I'll just use something for example):

```
p = subprocess.Popen("cat sample.txt | grep 'patternA'  | sed 'something' >> ~/out.txt", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print p.communicate()
```

I got `('', None)` printed out, and also when I checked the `~/out.txt` file, there's nothing printed as expected with the bash command given (assuming patternA exists in file sample.txt)

Is this the right way to use subprocess to run bash commands in pythong? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hmm for now I'm just a bit confused in terms of how to capture say the output of "cat sample.txt" and pipe that output to "grep 'patternA' then capture the new output to a file, all using subprocess...

Answer (score 3):

There is a number of minor problems with your code, but on the whole, yes, this is how you run a subprocess.

- Prefer `subprocess.run` over bare `Popen` when you can. This would also avoid the behavior you regard as confusing; see the next bullet point.
- As such, if you do run `Popen` and then `communicate`, the output from that is a tuple with two values, the standard output and the standard error of the finished process.
- But you are redirecting standard output to a file, so of course `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` is going to be unnecessary and produce nothing. (Because you don't capture `stderr` with `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`, it ends up containing `None`; if there is any error output, it is simply displayed to the user, and invisible to Python.)
- Your shell script is horribly overcomplicated. Reducing it to a single process would avoid the need for `shell=True` which is [generally something you should strive for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)
- But even more fundamentally, the script could be reimplemented in native Python, which would make it both more versatile, as well as easier to understand for anyone who is not familiar with both shell script and Python. (Granted, the shell formulation would be a lot more succinct, at least after refactoring.)

The obvious Python implementation would look like

```
from pathlib import Path
...
with open("sample.txt", "r") as lines, \
        Path("~/out.txt").expanduser().open("w") as output:
    for line in lines:
        if "patternA" in line:
            output.write(line.replace('foo', 'bar'))
```

where obviously we have to guess wildly at what your `sed` script actually does, as you have replaced it with a placeholder.

The same with `subprocess.run` and avoiding the shell programming antipatterns,

```
from pathlib import Path
...
with Path("~/out.txt").expanduser.open("w") as output:
    subprocess.run(
        ['sed', '/patternA/something', 'sample.txt'],
        stdout=output, text=True, check=True)
```

You want to avoid the [useless `cat`]([useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and the [useless `grep`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#grep); and with those out of the way, you don't need a pipeline, and thus no shell.

If you want to retrieve status information from the subprocess, assign the result from `subprocess.run` to a variable you can examine, say `r`; the error status will be in `r.resultcode` (though with `check=True` it's guaranteed to be 0).

Python won't let you mix `capture_output=True` with `stdout=...` and/or `stderr=...` so if you want to see whether there is error output (there could be a warning message from some tools even when they succeed) you have to split the operation. Perhaps like this:

```
import logging
from pathlib import Path
...
r = subprocess.run(
    ['sed', '/patternA/something', 'sample.txt'],
    capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
with Path("~/out.txt").expanduser().open("w") as output:
    output.write(r.stdout)
if r.stderr:
    logging.warn(r.stderr)
```

As a final aside, `os.path.expanduser()` or `pathlib.Path.expanduser()` are necessary to resolve `~/out.txt` to a file in your home directory.  You should generally never need to `os.chdir()` to find a file; just specify its path name if it's not in the current directory. See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Comment: For (much) more on these topics, see also [my answer to the near identically titled question _Running Bash commands in Python_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538)

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
import os, subprocess

with open("sample.txt", "w") as f:
    print("patternA1\npatternA2\nhello\nhi", file=f)

p = subprocess.Popen(
    "cat sample.txt | grep 'patternA' | sed 's/A/B/' > out.txt", 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

`out.txt` has been populated.

```
>>> p.communicate()
(b'', None)
>>> print(open('out.txt').read(), end='')
patternB1
patternB2
```

As you're using the shell and redirecting the output directly to a file - you're essentially doing an `os.system()` call.

```
>>> os.remove('out.txt')
>>> os.system("cat sample.txt | grep 'patternA' | sed 's/A/B/' > out.txt")
0
>>> print(open('out.txt').read(), end='')
patternB1
patternB2
```

Comment: Like the documentation already says, you should probably prefer `subprocess` over `os.system`, though probably not specifically `subprocess.Popen` if you can use one of the higher-level functions like `subprocess.check_call()`or `subprocess.run()`. The former is only a few characters longer than `os.system()` but provides several benefits.