# How to save some image from plot to the file in my desktop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

When I run this part of code (run a function) and then I see my folder in my desktop , there is nothing in there. Why? I expect that I see some PNG file in my folder of my desktop but I can't see them and they don't save in my folder

```
def curve(lisst , m):
  for i in lisst:
    if i in m.columns :
      r = plt.figure()
      plt.title(i)
      plt.plot(m.Time , m[i])
      plt.savefig(r"C:\Users\parsa\Desktop\kholase\image{}.png".format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to first check your [current working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory) using

```
import os
os.getcwd
```

Then check if the plot is saved there with the name you are specifying or not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might just have the wrong command on `plt.save`, try `plt.savefig` instead?

EDIT:

Might be a few things that are going wrong here, but assuming "lisst" is a list of column names and "m" is a pandas dataframe with "Time" as a datetime column (not index!), this might work:

```
# Set path explicitly as a variable with escapes (assuming Windows)
path = "C:\\Users\\parsa\\Desktop\\kholase\\"

# Check if path to the path exists and if not, create it
import os
if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

# Define the function
def curve(lisst , m):
    for i in lisst:
        if i in m.columns:
            # Create figure and axis separately
            fig, ax = plt.subplots()
            # Set title
            plt.title(i) # `fig.suptitle(i)` works too
            # Plot on the axis
            ax.plot(m.Time , m[i])

            # Concatenate path with f-string filename and save figure
            fig.savefig(path + f"image{i}.png", format="png")

# Call the function to produce the plots
curve(lisst, m)
```

Instead of `fig.savefig` just `plt.savefig` should work the same here.