# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file1.txt'

Tags: python, file

```
with open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as x, open('file2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as y:
```

My code is in the same directory as the files. How come I am getting this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it works. You can print `os.getcwd()` just to be sure.