# Logging all commands of Shell Script to log file

Tags: bash, shell, hive

Hello all after hours of google searching hoping somebody here can provide direction.

Currently I have a .sh file which I run in putty to kick off a process.  The current way I do this is:

```
sh /filepath/file.sh >> /filepath/file_date.log
```

While this works; I find it cumbersome to make sure I do the >> and logfile path correct for each of the .sh files I invoke.

The current contents of my .sh file are as such:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

frstdt=`date -d "last monday - 2 week" +"%m%d%Y"`;
scnddt=`date -d "last sunday - 1 week" +"%m%d%Y"`;
tday=`date -d "$date" +"%m_%d_%Y"`;
frstdtem=`date -d "last monday - 2 week" +"%m/%d/%Y"`;
scnddtem=`date -d "last sunday - 1 week" +"%m/%d/%Y"`

cd /filepath/
/filepath/cloak-hive -f query.hql

--Here I use hive -e to get some results from the query and write them to a .csv file.

ehco "Contents of email" | mailx -s "Subject" -a "Attchement" -me@email.com
```

What I am trying to understand is what I can add to the beginning of the .sh file to log all of the actions that take place, the map/reduce updates HIVE etc. I can see all this now when using the >> command when calling the .sh but am lookign to simplify this for others on the team.  I have tried using exec trap exec; | tee and other version of that but can not get anything to work.  I do not need to see anything in the console after I enter sh /filepath/filename.sh  I just want everthing to show up in the log with the log file name having the dat it runs in the file name(which is why I have tday as a variable; I would like it to show as /filepath/filename_$tday.log

Comment: `set -x` output goes to stderr and it is already there so redirecting stderr to stdout could be enough `sh /filepath/file.sh 2>&1 >> /filepath/file_date.log`

Comment: That is what I am currently doing.  What I'm trying to understand is if there is a command I put in the .sh file that would eliminate the need for >>filepath/file_date.log.  so that the log file is created automatically when running the .sh fiel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the script with `sh` is an error. See [Difference between `sh` and `bash`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash)

If I am guessing correctly what you are trying to ask,
my suggestion would be to create a simple wrapper, like

```
#!/bin/sh
/filepath/file.sh >> /filepath/file_$(date +%F).log
```

Your scripts should have a valid [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and you need to `chmod +x` both to be able to use that facility instead of spelling out `sh` or `bash`. Then you also don't need to keep track of which shell to use for which script.

I would also refactor your Bash script slightly.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x

# Use modern POSIX syntax for command substitution
tday=$(date -d "$date" +"%m_%d_%Y")
frstdtem=$(date -d "last monday - 2 week" +"%m/%d/%Y")
scnddtem=$(date -d "last sunday - 1 week" +"%m/%d/%Y")
# Don't call the same date commands again; instead, just remove slashes
frstdt=${frstdtem//\//}
scnddt=$(scnddtem//\//}

# Probably avoid cd, but depends
# See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory
cd /filepath/
/filepath/cloak-hive -f query.hql

--Here I use hive -e to get some results from the query and write them to a .csv file.

# Don't misspell echo or Attachment
echo "Contents of email" | mailx -s "Subject" -a "Attachment" -me@example.com
```

Using the most insane possible date format will create troubles down the road; I would recommend using ISO 8601 machine-readable YYYY-MM-DD date format for everything except possibly human display (but better yet, train your humans) but I did not change that part.

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I am new to this and the processes I use are based on .sh files provided by the previous colleague who used them.  I am doing my best to adapt and update where I can.   For the wrapper portion is that a separate .sh file I save and call for each job, or is that a command that goes in the top of the .sh file under the #!/bin/bash.  Sorry if I am misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: That would be a new script which you save in a file and run instead of the main script, so you don't have to remember the redirections etc yourself; the script fills those in for you. But I obviously had to guess which parts to parametrize and whether this is automatable in the first place. If it always requires human input, make a script which accepts an argument (which turns up in `"$1"`)

Comment: Thank you for that, that makes it clearer. I will try this out, and read up on the two links you provided.

Comment: Also for the date command to remove slashes could you explain how that works.  Because there are some files I have where the date is done with _ instead and I would like to remove those when necessary.

Comment: Read about [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/s/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)

Answer (score 1):

the best way to do it is:

```
command >> /filepath/logfile.log 2>&1
```

put it in your script,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't advise this praxis, but if you really want to do this, you can do a

```
exec >> /filepath/file_date.log 2>&1
```

as the first statement in your script.