# Subprocess.Popen does not give output

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have the following code:

```py
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
if os.path.isfile('../'):
    cmd = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '../')
    proc = Popen(["python3", "-m", cmd], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    progRunning = True
    while progRunning:
        try:
            output, error = proc.communicate()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("Program Forcequit")
            progRunning = False
            proc.kill()
    print('Process finished')
```

Where `../` is the directory to a file. This program is supposed to run `../` and stop itself when it receives a `KeyboardInterrupt`. However, when I try to run this code,
`print` statements do not work. Here is the code in the `../` to test:

```py
test.py
from time import *
while True:
    sleep(1)
    print("Hello World")
```

I am expecting an output of `Hello World!` every 1 second. I instead get no output. How do I fix this?

Comment: `../` is not a valid command, and [`os.getcwd()` is unnecessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Comment: Bro can you read the whole post please? '../' is a placeholder name for the name of the file I want to run

Comment: What makes you think I didn't (and what makes you think I'm a "bro")?

Comment: Because '../' is a placeholder name for the file

Comment: `communicate`  finishes when the other process is finished. The other process is never finished in this case, so this just keeps waiting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this script. Firstly, the condition `os.path.isfile('../')` is always false, because `..` is a directory, not a file. It should be `os.path.isfile('../test.py')`. Secondly, you should remove the `-m` option in the python call, because this loads test.py as a module, but does not execute it, so the script is never started. Thirdly, communicate is blocked until your script has finished, and the output is buffered, so nothing happens until the buffer is full (which can take quite some time). And finally, the output is put in the variable `output`, so in order to write the output to screen you should also add a `print(output`) in your main script.

I am wondering if running the test.py as an external python script is really required for your needs. Most probably you can better import as a normal python module

Comment: The reason why I can't use an import statement is because I want the program to execute when someone inputs the filename. When I try 'print output' it repeatedly returns an empty bytestring.

Comment: I you are in control of the contents of test.py, you could add a function `run()` which starts the script. Then you can replace your Popen with test.run().

Answer (score 1):

As Eelco pointed out, Communicate blocks until process completion, So if u want to read and print the output of the child process try

```
while True:
    lines = proc.stdout.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        print (line)
```

Comment: When I try this I get a ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: That means Your subprocess gets terminated before/while this code executes.