# Plotting Avg. AREA income against Price from US_Housing dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Plotting Avg. Area Income vs Price

plt.plot(usa_housing['Avg. Area Income'], usa_housing['Price'], color = 'red', marker = 'o')

# Giving title and label names
plt.title('Avg. Area Income Vs Price', fontsize = 14)
plt.xlabel('Avg. Area Income', fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel('Price', fontsize = 14)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Output return:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_12188\450110948.py in <module>

      3 # Plotting Avg. Area Income vs Price

      4 

----> 5 plt.plot(usa_housing['Avg. Area Income'], usa_housing['Price'], color = 'red', marker = 'o')

      6 

      7 # Giving title and label names

NameError: name 'usa_housing' is not defined
```

I want to get a plot of Avg. Area Income against Price

Comment: Well, you first need to read your data into a dataframe. Somehting like `usa_housing = pd.read_csv(.....filename....)`.

Comment: I am still getting the same error JohanC.

Comment: File name is USA_Hosing.csv right? I ahve been stucked here for days now. I need help

Comment: If the file isn't in the "current" directory, you would need to give the full path. You can't get the *same* error if you assign `usa_housing = pd.read_csv('............../USA_Hosing.csv')` before calling `plt.plot`. Note that I have no way to know how your file is named.

Comment: "current folder?"  please clarify.  in the tutorial i am using a different name is used.

Comment: 1. # Plotting Avg. Area Income vs Price
2. plt.plot(housing_price[‘Avg. Area Income’], housing_price[‘Price’], color=’red’, marker=’o’)
3.
4. # Giving title and label names
5. plt.title(‘Avg. Area Income Vs Price’, fontsize=14)
6. plt.xlabel(‘Avg. Area Income’, fontsize=14)
7. plt.ylabel(‘Price’, fontsize=14)
8. plt.grid(True)
9.
10. plt.show() 
this is the code the tutor used.

Comment: Well, you didn't copy the part where your tutor read the csv file and assigned it to a dataframe named `housing_price`. Maybe your tutor put that code somewhere earlier in the chapter.  The concept of a "current folder" (or directory) is both elementary, and at the same time hard to explain if you don't know it already.  See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory

Comment: I am still getting the same error after doing the needful:
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
spreadsheet = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Hamaboi Care Limited\Documents\CSV\USA_Housing.csv')
I got the same error message:
NameError: name 'USA_Housing' is not defined

The path is correct.
Please help.

Comment: Instead of `spreadsheet = pd.read_csv(...)` you could write `USA_Housing = pd.read_csv(...)`

Comment: Thanks  JohanC it worked perfectly.
Can you take me n as a student or protégé?