# How to write to file in GitHub Actions using Python?

Tags: python, file, github, github-actions, writefile

I want to write a text to file using **GitHub Actions** but I don't know how to do it.

I've tried:

```py
def write(path, text):
    file = open(path, 'w')
    file.write(text)
    file.close()
```

but nothing has changed.

But if I run it on local machine it is still works.

Comment: What do you mean by nothing has changed? Do you mean that the file is not present, the file contents are empty, or the file contents are the same?

Comment: Where are you expecting to see that file? It's (presumably) being written to the runner, which is an ephemeral environment.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, file contents are the same

Comment: Are you writing to the correct location? What if you open the file again via code?

Comment: If you still need help, please [edit] to provide more details about what you expected and how you determined that the expected output was not found in the file. A very common beginner mistake is looking in the wrong directory; perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Comment: You actually need to `push` the file after the update, for the changes to appear on the repository after the Github Action workflow run.

Answer (score -3):

```
def write(filename, text):

    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        file.write(text)

filename = 'example.txt'

text = '12works!'

write(filename, text)
```

The text is what you going to write into the file

Comment: This is unlikely to solve the issue they're having, as it's the same code other than `open` being changed to a context manager.