# crontab: I have to run a script every 5 minutes, it runs but it doesn't work

Tags: linux, cron, sh, centos7

```
*/5 * * * * root /mnt/efs/fs1/ec2Apache/validacao.sh
```

the script executes the echo command and sends the text to an online.txt file, however when executed by crontab the online.txt file is not found

when run normally without crontab the script works

**erro:**

Mar 30 16:46:01 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx.ec2.internal CROND[99999]: (root) CMDOUT (/mnt/efs/fs1/ec2Apache/validacao.sh: line 14: dir/online.txt: No such file or directory)

Comment: Use the absolute pathname of the `online.txt` file. The script's working directory isn't what you expect.

Comment: It's looking for `~root/dir/online.txt`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info . Good luck.

Comment: The duplicate has a number of troubleshooting steps. If you still need more help, please [edit] to indicate what you have done to debug the problem; but this is almost certainly a simple case of [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Answer (score -1):

Try in below way

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/bash /mnt/efs/fs1/ec2Apache/validacao.sh

or

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/sh /mnt/efs/fs1/ec2Apache/validacao.sh