# How to access a script inside a child directory of a parent directory in $PATH

Tags: bash

I have the following path in my `$PATH`: `/home/ubuntu/parent-dir/scripts`.
I can access every scripts that's inside of the `scripts` directory.
However, I would like to access a script inside of `/home/ubuntu/parent-dir/scripts/child-dir` without editing my `$PATH`. Is it possible

example:
`/home/ubuntu/parent-dir/scripts/child-dir/script.sh`

Comment: Can't you write the path to the called script in the calling script? Maybe `child-dir/script.sh`?

Comment: No, there is no way to access a subdirectory of a directory on the `PATH` without specifying the whole path. Not a programming question; voting to close.

Comment: @Abra That doesn't work; the OS resolves relative directory paths from the user's current directory, not the program's directory (though in many languages, you can find the file the script is in, and take it from there; but that is not what the OP is asking). See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Comment: @tripleee, ended up adding it to `$PATH` ;)

Answer (score 1):

While I don't consider this good practice (i.e. adding the other directory to `$PATH` is simpler and better), but you certainly *could* programmatically iterate over the individual paths defined in `$PATH`, and each time check if the script exists relative to there. If so, execute it, otherwise continue looping.

```bash
exec_rel_to_PATH() (
  IFS=:; for p in $PATH; do [ -x "$p/$1" ] && {
    s="$1"; shift; "$p/$s" "$@"; return
  }; done;
)

exec_rel_to_PATH child-dir/script.sh
```

Note: This is not limited in childward direction. `exec_rel_to_PATH ../../uncle-dir/other-scripts/script.sh` should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up adding to `$PATH="$PATH:/home/ubuntu/parent-dir/scripts/child-dir`