# Trying to run python scripts on Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, etl

I'm trying to run a DAG in Airflow that will execute Python scripts in my environment. I tested the commands from the same directory as the file, and the logic appears to be correct, but in Airflow, it simply does not execute the scripts. I added a print statement in the first task, and the response is:

```
[2023-11-17, 07:00:07 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:137} INFO - The script /opt/***/src/etl/extract.py either does not exist or cannot be executed
[2023-11-17, 07:00:07 UTC] {python.py:177} INFO - Done. Returned value was: None
[2023-11-17, 07:00:07 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1323} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=run_scripts_daily, task_id=run_extract, execution_date=20231117T070006, start_date=20231117T070007, end_date=20231117T070007
[2023-11-17, 07:00:07 UTC] {local_task_job.py:208} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2023-11-17, 07:00:07 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2578} INFO - 1 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours. `subprocess.run` seem to be the solution, but I can't configure them correctly. I would be grateful if someone could help :)

My dag:

```
from airflow.decorators import dag
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import subprocess
import os

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5),
}

def run_extract():
    airflow_home = '/opt/airflow/'
    script_path = os.path.join(airflow_home, 'src/etl/extract.py')
    if os.path.exists(script_path) and os.access(script_path, os.X_OK):
        subprocess.run(['python', script_path], shell=True)
    else:
        print(f'O script {script_path} não existe ou não pode ser executado')

def run_pre_validate():
    #subprocess.run(['python', '../src/validators/pre_validate.py'])
    pass

def run_transform():
    # subprocess.run(['python', '../src/etl/transform.py'], shell=True)
    pass

def run_pos_validate():
    # subprocess.run(['python', '../src/validators/pos_validate.py'])
    pass

def run_load():
    # subprocess.run(['python', '/src/etl/load.py'])
    pass

@dag(
    "run_scripts_daily",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 12, 1),
    max_active_runs=1,
    schedule="@daily",
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
)
def run_scripts_daily():
    opr_run_extract = PythonOperator(
        task_id="run_extract",
        python_callable=run_extract
    )

    opr_run_pre_validate = PythonOperator(
        task_id="run_pre_validate",
        python_callable=run_pre_validate
    )

    opr_run_transform = PythonOperator(
        task_id="run_transform",
        python_callable=run_transform
    )

    opr_run_pos_validate = PythonOperator(
        task_id="run_pos_validate",
        python_callable=run_pos_validate
    )

    opr_run_load = PythonOperator(
        task_id="run_load",
        python_callable=run_load
    )

    opr_run_extract >> opr_run_pre_validate >> opr_run_transform >> opr_run_pos_validate >> opr_run_load

run_scripts_daily_dag = run_scripts_daily()
```

Comment: When the computer tells you a file doesn't exist, it's nearly always telling the truth. A typical beginner mistake is supplying the wrong directory name. You have obscured the actual path in the question, so all we can tell you is really what's already in the error message. Maybe see [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory) for a possible explanation.

Comment: As an aside, running Python as a subprocess of itself is often dubious, but of course, we can't tell without access to the other scripts whether it makes sense here. Often the proper solution is to `import` the code you want to run into the current script, and simply call one of the Python functions you imported. If the scripts were not written to support being imported, this might require some refactoring. Perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/69778466/874188

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is the best solution but I tried copying the .py script to the docker container and it worked.