# Run python script from Command Prompt

Tags: python

I know how to run a python script from the python idle but I can't figure out how to run it from the terminal.

I thought that it might work by using "run test.py"

```
print("Hello World")
print("This is a test")
print(1+1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run a python script, you just have to write `python YOUR FILE HERE.py` But before doing this, remember to set the location of command prompt to the location of your file using the command `cd YOUR FILE ADDRESS`

Comment: You can run a file in any directory; the current working directory is just a convenience which removes the requirement to write out the path. See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Comment: Separately, file names with spaces in them need to be quoted or otherwise disambiguated. What exactly works depends on your platform. For Windows, probably use double quotes.

Comment: `python` may or may not work. On Windows, probably try `py` instead. On some Linux platforms, you want `python3`. But again, all of this and more is thoroughly explained in existing duplicates; please don't post new answers to simple questions when a duplicate probably contains more details and nuance than you are able or willing to put in a new answer.

Comment: Ok I am new to the platform, will try to improve this next time. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you can call the Python program from the Command Prompt and tell it which file to execute. From the Command Prompt, simply type:

`python test.py`

For more information visit this link:

[Here](https://learnpython.com/blog/run-python-script-windows/#:%7E:text=Run%20Python%20Code%20from%20the%20Command%20Prompt&text=To%20get%20an%20interactive%20session,python%20and%20hit%20Enter%20again.)