# If statement not working via bash script, but working on cli, why?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement, conditional-formatting

can anyone kindly help me

```
for f in $(grep -Ev '^(#|$)' $(readlink -f $(git config --get core.excludesfile)) | awk '{$1=$1};1' | tr -d '\r' ); do for g in $(git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard); do if [ $f == $g ]; then echo "ok $f $g"; fi; ls $f; done; done
```

I'm testing the above script, when I do it directly on bash cli it works as expected, but when I execute it via a script, it doesn't work. Mainly the if statement doesn't get executed, can anybody tell me why or any alternatives?

I tried with different thing, like bringing `shopt` and mainly operating on the if statement, every time when on cli it works, but with a script it doesn't!

Here is the code converted from a one-liner:

```
for f in $(grep -Ev '^(#|$)' $(readlink -f $(git config --get core.excludesfile)) | awk '{$1=$1};1' | tr -d '\r' ); do 
    for g in $(git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard); do
        if [ $f == $g ]; then 
            echo "ok $f $g"
        fi 
        ls $f
    done
done
```

Comment: We really can't know. Generally, anything you can type on the command line will work the same in a script (save for interactive features like history expansion, aliases, etc). What should this script do and where does it go wrong when you run it with `bash -x scriptname`?

Comment: Try pasting your code here https://www.shellcheck.net/#

Comment: @tripleee the script will match it's pattern of the global gitignore file to pattern of ignored file (which I usually bring by `git ls-files --others --ignored --exculde-standard`) for that repository where the script is located...

But when I run it, I don't see the "ok <file> <file>" as you see in that code, which on cli it does

Comment: @9769953 I execute it by `bash <script_name>

Comment: `git` (like basically every other command) operates in the current working directory, not in the directory where the script is stored. Possible duplicate of [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Comment: _doesn't work_ is probably the most meaningless problem description possible. We don't know in what way it didnt work, we don't know how you executed your script, we don't even know whether execution reaches the `if` (this can depend on your shell options). I suggest that you do some basic debugging first (for instance by turning on tracing with `set -x` and if there still is an open question, ask here with a concrete, complete problem description.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for ... in` loops are an antipattern, use `while IFS= read -r` loops instead, see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001. There are various other issues that http://shellcheck.net could help you with as your script will currently do various different things based on environment settings, contents of the directory you run it from, names of files you run it on, etc.

Best I can tell from your code, this (using bash 4.3 or later to test an array index existence with `-v`) seems to be what you're trying to do but it's an untested guess since you didn't provide sample input and expected output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A gitLsFiles
while IFS= read -r file; do
    gitLsFiles["$file"]=1
done < <(
    git ls-files --others --ignored --exclude-standard
)

while IFS= read -r file; do
    if [[ -v gitLsFiles["$file"] ]]; then
        echo "ok $file"
    fi
    ls "$file"
done < <(
    git config --get core.excludesfile |
        awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} !/^(#|$)/ { $1=$1; print }'
)
```

That `awk` command will convert all white space in the `git config` output to single blank chars, just like your current script does, I don't know if you really want to do that or not.

In the above I'm assuming you don't REALLY want to call `git ls-files` once per line output from `git config`, nor do you really want to `echo` the same file name twice and do an `ls` for the same `git config` output line multiple times. I also assume you just want to remove `\r`s from the end of lines, not everywhere, and if your input can contain line ending `\r`s then you need to remove them BEFORE testing for `^$`, not after so I moved where that happens. Finally, I'm assuming that neither of those `git` commands output file names that contains newlines.