# Julia -space in the path

Tags: path, julia

I have a file "Master.dss" located in the path is: `C:\Users\GG\OneDrive - GG\data\8500-Node\Master.dss`

I've used the following syntax to read the file `Master.dss`:

```
path = pwd()*raw"data\8500-Node\Master.dss"
```

I am expecting to store `"C:\Users\GG\OneDrive - GG\data\8500-Node\Master.dss"` in path

However, it sounds that Julia is not happy with the space or the hyphen "-". I've got the following error:

```
[ERROR 242] Redirect file not found: \"C:\\Users\\GG\\OneDrive\"")
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: The spaces are more likely the culprit here, but I'm not familiar enough with Julia to tell you how to quote them.

Comment: Why do you need to involve `pwd` at all, though? Just use the relative path. See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `joinpath()` to guarantee the path's format, and `@__DIR__` to "[return the current working directory if run from a REPL or if evaluated by julia -e .*](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@__DIR__)"

```
curr_dir = @__DIR__
dir_path = "data/8500-Node/"
filename = "Master.dss"

path = joinpath(curr_dir, dir_path, filename)
```

Although [this Replit](https://replit.com/@itsjayway/ClassicRightQuerylanguage#main.jl) is Linux-based, the implementation should still work across platforms.

---

Sources:

https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.joinpath
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@__DIR__

Also, https://discourse.julialang.org/t/behavior-of-the-pwd-statement-windows-10/19673

Comment: I am using pwd() to generalise the code so the other users do not need to change the path based on their machine.

Using the joinpath, I still have the same error:

"[ERROR 242] Redirect file not found: \"C:\\Users\\GG\\OneDrive\""

Answer (score 1):

`joinpath` proposed in the other answer surely works. Perhaps you are providing some wrong file name.
Consider this code:

```
julia> mkdir("Path with space")
"Path with space"

julia> cd("Path with space")

julia> joinpath(pwd(), raw"data\8500-Node\Master.dss")
"C:\\Users\\pszufe\\Path with space\\data\\8500-Node\\Master.dss"
```

You can clearly see that everything works as expected.

However, if you have issue of back and forwards slashes you could also add `normpath` to this code which nicely makes slashes to match the operating system:

```
julia> joinpath(pwd(), normpath("data/8500-Node/Master.dss"))
"C:\\Users\\pszufe\\Path with space\\data\\8500-Node\\Master.dss"
```