# Bash script not running on network connection

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, networking

I have written some php code that I want to be run automatically every time I connect to my home network. To do this, I created the following bash script that I then put in the if-up.d directory on my local machine that is running ubuntu.

```
#!bin/bash

HOME_SSID={name of local network}
CURR_SSID=$(iwgetid -r)

if [[ $HOME_SSID == $CURR_SSID ]]
then
  sudo php transfer.php
fi
```

I've run the bash script through the command line and the php file runs just fine. However, I am having issues getting it to run by default when connecting to a network. Is there a log file that is generated where I can see what issue might be coming up? Or is there a change that I need to make to guarantee that the file actually gets run? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

First, fix the shebang (absolute), then redirect the errors to a file

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 2> /tmp/my.log

HOME_SSID={name of local network}
CURR_SSID=$(iwgetid -r)

if [[ $HOME_SSID == $CURR_SSID ]]
then
  sudo php transfer.php
fi
```

Comment: Thirdly, probably don't expect it to run in the directory where you have `transfer.php`. See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)

Comment: O.P. if you try this technique, also add `set -x` as the 2nd line of your script. this will add output like `+ [[ something == something ]]` (the `+` is the "debug" prompt). This way you can see what values you variables are holding. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Now when I run it through the command line, it is creating a log file. I want the script to run automatically when connecting to a new network, and that's why it is in the /etc/network/if-up.d directory. Is there a reason that it is not running when I want it to?

Comment: How do you run it from command line?

Comment: I got it to start working. Originally, the bash script had a .sh extension but removing that seemed to fix the issue. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Extensions have no meaning in linux, so the shebang or some other thing you didn't mention fixed the issue.