# filepath doesn't have clarity whether it's only the path or file with path

Tags: pandas, path, read-csv

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html#io-read-csv-table

I see you frequently say FILEPATH_OR_BUFFER   with no explanation that the path includes the file name  not in the variable name   or in the explanation.    One can read this and understant it as only the file path  where it's maybe more true that it's  file name  and optionally a path   where if the path is not there it uses the working directory?

I think it's many places.

This is a request to fix documentation, not code.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming questions. If you have feedback to the Pandas maintainers, use their support channels. But really, this seems like a basic computer literacy question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory)