# Problem with compile .Tex in Visual studio code with LaTeX workshop

Tags: latex, latexmk

It won't run for some reason that i don't understand

Here is the compiler log:

```
Reverting Windows console CPs to (in,out) = (437,65001)
Initial Win CP for (console input, console output, system): (CP437, CP65001, CP1252)
I changed them all to CP1252
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 31 Jan. 2024. Version 4.83.

Latexmk: Wildcards in file names didn't match any files
Use
   latexmk -help
to get usage information
```

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Answer (score 0):

to this problem, I try to reinstall VS code and MikTeX. Then I move the .tex file to another location. Before that, it was in onedrive folder and it is a clone repository from Github. After done all of the step, it work again. And beside that, i think the problem was i change some setting in MikTex which i don't know how to fix.
Thanks tripleee for point out the problem with my question and provide link to help with that.