# Pandas dataframe can't find CSV file that I have

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am getting a `FileNotFoundError` for this section of code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("EURUSD_Candlestick_1_D_BID_05.05.2003-28.10.2023.csv")
```

However, I have this file in my Downloads and it is spelled correctly. I am using Jupyter Notebook in VScode. It also says to check if the file is to be read in binary mode but I'm not sure what this means. Do you know if I need it in a specific directory or if this isn't working for another reason?

Comment: should either put absolute path to the file `/home/my-username/Downloads/my-csv.csv`, or have the file in the same folder as the runtime.

Comment: It's looking in the **current directory**, which is not necessarily the same directory as the python script.  You can use this to display the current directory `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Comment: In Jupyter Notebook, you may also be able to just type `pwd`, standing for 'print working directory', in a cell and execute to get the current working directory. Works on most unix-based system. YMMV on Windows. That combined with `%cd` to change the current working directory persistently (for the present session) in a Jupyter Notebook is generally useful.