# How To Fix "IndexError: list index out of range" when launched by Systemd?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to fix this issue:

```
 crawl_oled.service - test OLED SSD1306
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/crawl_oled.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-03-06 08:30:14 EST; 2min 33s ago
    Process: 200235 ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 200600 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/luma-env/luma.examples/examples/OLED_INFO.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 200600 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 609ms

Mar 06 08:30:14 raspberrypi python3[200600]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 06 08:30:14 raspberrypi python3[200600]:   File "/home/pi/luma-env/luma.examples/examples/OLED_INFO.py", line 299, in <module>
Mar 06 08:30:14 raspberrypi python3[200600]:     run_ext()
Mar 06 08:30:14 raspberrypi python3[200600]:   File "/home/pi/luma-env/luma.examples/examples/OLED_INFO.py", line 59, in run_ext
Mar 06 08:30:14 raspberrypi python3[200600]:     random_py = random.choice(Local_List)
Mar 06 08:30:14 raspberrypi python3[200600]:   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/random.py", line 347, in choice
Mar 06 08:30:14 raspberrypi python3[200600]:     return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
Mar 06 08:30:14 raspberrypi python3[200600]: IndexError: list index out of range
Mar 06 08:30:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: crawl_oled.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`
Mar 06 08:30:14 raspberrypi systemd[1]: crawl_oled.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

...

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /etc/os-release  PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)" NAME="Debian GNU/Linux" VERSION_ID="11" VERSION="11 (bullseye)" VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye ID=debian HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/" SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

The script used to run normally at startup but have failed since I added the `random` function to randomise script launching from Luma Examples.

Here's the part from the script that is failing

```
def run_ext():
    i = 0
    while True:
        try:
            # Command to run "OTHER".py
            ####random_file=random.choice(os.listdir())
            Local_List = [each for i, each in enumerate(os.listdir(current_working_directory)) if each.endswith('1.py')]
            random_py = random.choice(Local_List)
            random_py = current_working_directory + '/' + str(random_py)
            print(random_py)
            sp.run(random_py, timeout=10)
        except sp.TimeoutExpired:
            break
```

When introducing i to `random_py = random.choice(Local_List[i])`, I get this following error:

```
crawl_oled.service - test OLED SSD1306
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/crawl_oled.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-03-06 08:52:57 EST; 2s ago
    Process: 216809 ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 30 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 217172 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/luma-env/luma.examples/examples/OLED_INFO.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 217172 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 545ms

Mar 06 08:52:56 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started test OLED SSD1306.
Mar 06 08:52:57 raspberrypi python3[217172]: /
Mar 06 08:52:57 raspberrypi python3[217172]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 06 08:52:57 raspberrypi python3[217172]:   File "/home/pi/luma-env/luma.examples/examples/OLED_INFO.py", line 299, in <module>
Mar 06 08:52:57 raspberrypi python3[217172]:     run_ext()
Mar 06 08:52:57 raspberrypi python3[217172]:   File "/home/pi/luma-env/luma.examples/examples/OLED_INFO.py", line 59, in run_ext
Mar 06 08:52:57 raspberrypi python3[217172]:     random_py = random.choice(Local_List[i])
Mar 06 08:52:57 raspberrypi python3[217172]: IndexError: list index out of range
Mar 06 08:52:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: crawl_oled.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 06 08:52:57 raspberrypi systemd[1]: crawl_oled.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Can someone teach me how to fix this issue and what's the best way to have this script work as expected:
pick a random example from the Luma Examples folder and run it for x seconds then go on with the rest of the main().
Worth noting that this same script run normally without error when lunched from Geany.

Comment: Your Python code was pretty broken; please review my attempt to fix it. Going forward, probably notice that you get a preview of what your post will look like below the editing pane. If your screen is wide enough, you also get a help button at the right of the editor’s menu strip, with a link to the full [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that the list is empty. In other words, the "problem" is that there are no files ending with `1.py` in `current_working_directory`. Look in a different directory, change the pattern, or add some files which actually match your pattern.

For debugging this, probably simply `print` the list just before the line which raises the exception. This should allow you to see whether the value matches your expectations, and if not, investigate why not. This basic debugging technique is essential, and will take you very far once you master it.

You haven't shown us how you launch this script from `systemd`; if you haven't specified a `WorkingDirectory=` directory in the `[Service]` section of the unit file, `systemd` will run it in `/`, the root directory, which is definitely not where you should store your Python files, even if you technically could, if you have `root` access.

Tangentially, the code to populate the list is pretty obscure and complex. You might want to replace it with something like

```
from pathlib import Path

...
        cwdobj = Path(current_working_directory)
        local_files = list(cwdobj.glob("*1.py"))
        # fail if there are no matches
        assert local_files
        random_py = random.choice(local_files)
        sp.run(str(random_py), timeout=10)
```

The legacy `glob` library has roughly similar functionality, but I think you'll appreciate how `pathlib.Path` encapsulates a directory entry in an object which you can query for its base name, file existence, file type, etc etc, as well as turn into a full path by simply converting it back to a string, like here.

This won't fix the problem you are struggling with, but simplifies your code to the point where it should be easier to debug it and/or develop it further.

(Also, if `current_working_directory` is what it says it is, this variable is entirely redundant. The operating system knows at all times which directory you are in. Perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904))

Comment: I have updated the answer to hopefully throw a bit more light into the darker corners.

Comment: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html is probably too heavy for a beginner question. I found a friendlier (to the point where you could even say "dumbed down") introduction to this particular `systemd` feature at https://www.baeldung.com/linux/systemd-service-working-directory (but this isn't a recommendation; I haven't vetted it in detail, and have in the past found Baeldung's pages to be of extremely variable quality).