# I'm encountering a FileNotFoundError in Python even though the file 'transactions.xlsx' exists in the same directory as my script

Tags: python, openpyxl

Here's the code snippet:

```
import openpyxl as xl

try:
    wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
    sheet = wb['Sheet1']
    cell = sheet['A1']
    print(cell.value)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print("FileNotFoundError:", e)
```

However, I'm getting the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
    wb = xl.load_workbook('transactions.xlsx')
  ...
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transactions.xlsx'
```

I attempted to load the 'transactions.xlsx' file using the xl.load_workbook() function from the openpyxl library in Python. I expected the script to successfully load the file since it exists in the same directory. However, I received a FileNotFoundError indicating that the file could not be found, despite it being present in the same folder.

Comment: Three things to consider: 

1. What directory is the script in
2. What directory is the file in
3. Which directory are you executing from

They all need to be the same directory, unless you specify relative or absolute pathing.

I would try using absolute path for all three.

Comment: As the above comment is asking, is your Excel file in the same directory as the script?

Comment: The same directory _as the script_ is not important. The same directory _as the shell that starts the script_ is important. @wandering-geek, ...the OP says _in the question title_ that the file is in the same directory as the script. Thus, the problem is clearly that their working directory is _not_ the same directory as that with both the script and the Excel file.

Comment: See [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory) -- it's _that_ directory, not the one your script is in, searched to find items opened with unqualified paths.

Comment: I solved the issues by making this change wb = xl.load_workbook('Python/dir/transactions.xlsx')

Comment: Is there one command that I can give at the beginning so that my whole code refers to  this path Python/dir/ automatically