# Can't activate Python environment after creating it in bash

Tags: python, bash

I have the following script `myenv.sh`:

```bash
#!bin/bash
echo "####### Install automated template ########"
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install ipykernel pandas seaborn scikit-learn
echo "######## Done ########"
```

So I run the script, and it creates the environment but doesn't stay activated. Perhaps it is exiting. So I tried this:

```bash
#!bin/bash
echo "####### Install automated template ########"
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install ipykernel pandas seaborn scikit-learn
source ${PWD}/.venv/bin/activate
echo "######## Done ########"
```

But nothing happens. Please, could you point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't stay activated for the same reason you have to source `activate` instead of executing it as a script.

Comment: To extend that: For your script to change the state of the shell that calls it, you need to use `source` to run _your script itself_ just as much as you need to use `source` to run `activate`.

Comment: BTW, `#!bin/bash` is wrong -- it should be `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, great catch!, and finally I solved it running with: `. ./myenv.sh`

Answer (score 0):

When you run a shell script that activates a venv, the activation only affects the sub-shell created for the script and not the shell of your script invoking `activate`. Once the script completes, the sub-shell is closed and any changes to the environment it introduced, including activation of the virtual environment, are lost.

Second script is buggy, because `PWD = pwd` is incorrect syntax for assigning command output to a variable (in fact you do not even call the `pwd` there). The correct syntax would be `PWD=$(pwd)` (note lack of spaces too), BUT...  this is unnecessary as `PWD` is a built-in variable that already contains the current directory, so you can instantly use `${PWD}`.

Comment: Furthermore, you don't need to know the absolute directory; you can simply use `.` for the current directory. See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Comment: I have changed the buggy code as suggested, but even if I change the source command to `sh ${PWD}/.venv/bin/activate` it doesn't activate the environment. Any other suggestion, please?

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_ and the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, even following the pointers in the section, I tried `ve() { source $1/bin/activate;  ve}` as indicated in the answer but no, it doesn't activate the environment

Comment: @Alexis, did you put that _in the script_ (where it wouldn't help at all) or _in the dotfiles of your interactive shell_ (where it would)? The idea of defining a shell function is to _replace_ the script with the function so you aren't invoking a subprocess in the first place.

Comment: (mind, if you're defining the function as a one-liner like that, you need a `;` before the `}`)