# I have received the FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Mammal'

Tags: python

My code is

```
file = open("Mammal", "r")
for line in file.readlines():
       print(line)
```

I am trying to create a file path

i have tried googling the pathway but cannot find anything that works. I have the file saved on desktop as Mammal. It was previously Mammal.txt

Comment: Is your *script* run from desktop as well? If not, you might need to provide absolute path to the file.

Comment: @matszwecja Even if the script is on the desktop, the current working directory might not be the desktop folder.

Comment: Your "file path" is "Mammal" which is relative to your current working directory. Try using an absolute pathname instead

Answer (score 0):

The file or a symlink to the file `Mammal` should be located in the directory from which you will invoke the script that will `open` it.

```
file = open("Mammal", "r") # <——- The file Mammal must always be in the current working directory from which you will call script.py whenever you will.
```

Since `Mammal` is on *`Desktop`*, from this directory, you may then invoke the script as follows

```
python3 path/to/script.py
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The file name shoukd be relative to your current working directory. See also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Comment: You are absolutely correct @tripleee. I’ve checked your post and funny enough I have actually done something like that before without knowing what was going on or why it worked the way it did.

Comment: @tripleee I have made the necessary edits. Please consider reviewing.