# How to refer to the filepath of test data in test sourcecode?

Tags: c, unit-testing, testing, makefile, automake

I'm using `Make` (`Automake`) to compile and execute unit tests. However these tests need to read and write test data. If I just specify a path, the tests only work from a specific directory. This is a problem, as first the test executables may be executed from a directory different than at compiletime by `make`, and secondly they should be executable even manually or in `VPATH`-builds, which currently brakes `make distcheck`

Even using `srcdir`, via config.h, isn't particularly useful, because it is of course evaluated at compiletime rather than at runtime. <del>What would be nice is, if the builddir would get passed at runtime instead.</del> What I think is necessary, is a way to get the srcdir relative to the builddir into the executable. This needs to be done/adjusted at runtime, due to the reasons written earlier. While this wouldn't solve the problem of being executed outside of the builddir, I don't think, that this is a particular problem, because, who would do that?

But would it be better to specify them via the command arguments or via the environment? And is it "better" to specify individual files or a generic directory? I would consider a `PATH`-like search behaviour overkill for just a test, or would that be recommended?

Or should I just give up and specify a absolute path? But I think, that would break `VPATH`-builds.

So the question is, how would I specify the path to a test file best, in terms of portability, interoperability, maintainability and common sense?

Comment: *"What would be nice is, if the builddir would get passed at runtime instead."* The executable (path and) name is given to `main()` as `argv[0]`.

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If your program accepts a file name argument, the argument should be relative to the current directory, or absolute. Perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Comment: @WeatherVane I know, but it probably wouldn't contain the whole path to the executable, and also this isn't exactly solving the problem of locating a different file. Or are you suggesting, that I should try to get the filepath relative to the executable, and try to resolve it by getting the execution path of the executable? I think that would trigger the follow-up question, how to portably get the dirname, but with as view lines as possible.

Comment: @WeatherVane is correct, usually; furthermore, tests are often started by scripts or in a test environment of some sort (Jenkins etc.) which has its own ways of referring to files and directories.

Comment: If it doesn't contain the whole path to executable, then the executable is in the CWD. You can extract the folder by looking for the last \ or / (system dependent) using `strrchr()`.

Comment: @Caulder Exactly, the data should be part of the repository which is used to build the tests and should be deployed together with the executable, into a location relative to it. That will, as a bonus,  make it possible to move the whole blob somewhere else manually and execute it from there (other drive, other machine, network location, whatever). You surely do not want absolute paths.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica It is, but it isn't installed (=deployed?). The "test environment" is the test harness of Automake.

Comment: @tripleee Can you elaborate on this?